# focus on parent dom but give outline to child dom

Tags: html, css

I have a html strucute which looks like this

```
<div class = "f">
   <a href="" class ="d" > 
      <span class ="b"> hello </span> 
   </a>
</div>
```

The activeElement is always the 'a' but I want to give to outline to span when 'a' is active. (By active I mean when we navigate by tab and 'a' becomes the activeElement)
I tried doing something like

```
.a:active {
  &.b:focus{
   outline : 1px solid white:
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/783v4g1d/).

```
<a href="" class ="d" > 
 <span class ="b"> hello </span> 
</a>
```

---

```
a:active > .b {
 outline: red solid 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want, when `a` is active `b` will get an outline:

```
.a:active {
  .b {
   outline : white solid 1px;
  }
}
```

Also your `outline` values are in the wrong order, so I changed them.

Comment: This won't work with traditional CSS fyi, it will need to be run through a parser (LESS, SASS, etc)

Comment: @BlakeA.Nichols I assumed he was.